# How do I control the placement of a UITableCell text label?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

How would I go about placing a cell label. here's my cell.detailTextLabel.text

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[[placesOutputArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] childAtIndex:1] stringValue];
```

I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
detailsLb = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 45, 250, 20)] autorelease];
```

I'm stuck on merging the two together somehow so that the cell.detailTextLabel.text is placed right where I want it.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following approach:

- Subclass UITableViewCell
- Override the super-method 'layoutSubviews'. Right there, you could simply set the 'frame' property of the detailTextLabel.

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I think the detailTextLabel frame is not editable. The simplest approach is to create a custom UITableViewCell with a xib file. Chose Style = "Custom" in the inspector and put a detail Label wherever you want. Don't forget to add the related IBOutlet to this label in your custom class.

Once done you can use your custom cell class instead of UITableViewCell in the -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:tableView CellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method

Comment: thanks! what if I'm not using a xib file? I can do this with code too?

Comment: Yes, of course! A little bit more expensive in terms of time and effort (expecially if you accept the interface rotation) but it will surely work :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Sub class `UITableViewCell`
2. You can also do this by adding a label to the cell's content view.

Like:

```
UILabel *details= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 45, 100, 20)];
[cell.contentView addSubview:details];
[details release];
```

Also you need to remove this label when you are reusing the cell. So you need to consider that also.